# Phalcon stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes

Tags: java, php, html, css, phalcon

My problem is about stylesheets and javascript that aren't loading when I'm using a second / in my URL.

When I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/theme.css" />` it works for my base route but stops working when I go deeper, such as `/home/webpage`.

These are the errors I am getting in my Chrome console:

[image: Chrome Errors]

Comment: use absolute urls

Comment: don't provide image hosted on external services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841310/is-there-some-way-to-add-an-asset-to-every-single-page-in-phalcon)

Essentially you need an assets manager. You can then load this assets manager in your main layout (if you have one) and have your other views extend your main layout.